# Magento Dynamic Map in a CMS page

Tags: php, google-maps, magento, session-variables

in the top links of my magento site there's one called "Store Locator".

When the user clicks on that link I would like to show him a page that contains a list of states:

```
<a href="locator?state=State1">State 1</a>
<a href="locator?state=State2">State 2</a>
<a href="locator?state=State3">State 3</a>
<a href="locator?state=State4">State 4</a>
```

After the user has selected the state, will appears a page with Google Maps with some markers (the markers represents the stores).

I know how to display the maps and get the markers from database but I don't know how can I implement this in Magento. How can I create the locator page? Should I use a CMS page for that? How can I put the PHP code inside? I need to access to session variable `$_GET`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a locator page for every state under:

Default: **app/design/frontend/default/default/template/YOURFOLDER/state_N.phtml**

Custom: **app/design/frontend/default/YOURCOMPANY/template/YOURFOLDER/state_N.phtml**

You also need to create a cms page for every state and put the following xml layout update in it under, **layout -> xml layout**:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="page/html" name="state_N" as="state.N" template="YOURFOLDER/state_N.phtml">
    </block>
</reference>
```

*N = state number*

Into the state_N.phtml pages use the following code to get your get or post variables:

```
$state = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('state');
```

Now you can link to this pages from the main locator link page by using:

```
<a href="{{store direct_url='cmspage?state=State4'}}">State 4</a>
```

There are many other ways to do this, but that's how i would resolve the problem.

Hope this helps.